# dovecot telnet localhost 143

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, dovecot

I have problem with dovecot, when im trying telnet localhost 143 i got

```
root@ubuntuserver:/etc/dovecot# telnet localhost 143
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Its systemctl status dovecot

```
dovecot.service - Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dovecot.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
 Active: active (running) since Mon 2024-02-12 14:20:12 UTC; 3min 18s ago
   Docs: man:dovecot(1)
         https://doc.dovecot.org/
 Main PID: 15458 (dovecot)
 Status: "v2.3.20 (80a5ac675d) running"
  Tasks: 4 (limit: 5673)
 Memory: 2.5M
    CPU: 20ms
 CGroup: /system.slice/dovecot.service
         ├─15458 /usr/sbin/dovecot -F
         ├─15459 dovecot/anvil
         ├─15460 dovecot/log
         └─15461 dovecot/config

    Feb 12 14:20:12 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: Starting dovecot.service - Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server...
    Feb 12 14:20:12 ubuntuserver dovecot[15458]: master: Dovecot v2.3.20 (80a5ac675d) starting up without any protocols (core dumps disabled)
    Feb 12 14:20:12 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: Started dovecot.service - Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server.
```

It's from logs :

```
2024-02-12T13:46:33.871791+00:00 ubuntuserver dovecot: master: Fatal: service(imap) access(/usr/lib/dovecot/imap) failed: No such file or directory
2024-02-12T13:57:23.398290+00:00 ubuntuserver dovecot: master: Fatal: Dovecot is already running with PID 14291 (read from /run/dovecot/master.pid)
2024-02-12T14:06:03.027267+00:00 ubuntuserver dovecot: master: Fatal: service(pop3) access(/usr/lib/dovecot/pop3) failed: No such file or directory
2024-02-12T14:06:43.544402+00:00 ubuntuserver dovecot: master: Fatal: service(pop3) access(/usr/lib/dovecot/pop3) failed: No such file or directory
2024-02-12T14:17:51.699300+00:00 ubuntuserver dovecot: master: Fatal: service(auth) getpwnam(vmail) failed: No such file or directory (See service auth { unix_listener /run/dovecot/auth-userdb { user } } setting)
2024-02-12T14:20:16.125234+00:00 ubuntuserver dovecot: master: Fatal: Dovecot is already running with PID 15458 (read from /run/dovecot/master.pid)

2024-02-12T14:06:01.874097+00:00 ubuntuserver dovecot: master: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=14776 uid=0 code=kill)
2024-02-12T14:06:02.986315+00:00 ubuntuserver dovecot: log(14294): Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)
2024-02-12T14:06:03.027267+00:00 ubuntuserver dovecot: master: Fatal: service(pop3) access(/usr/lib/dovecot/pop3) failed: No such file or directory
2024-02-12T14:06:43.544402+00:00 ubuntuserver dovecot: master: Fatal: service(pop3) access(/usr/lib/dovecot/pop3) failed: No such file or directory
2024-02-12T14:08:10.468783+00:00 ubuntuserver dovecot: master: Dovecot v2.3.20 (80a5ac675d) starting up without any protocols (core dumps disabled)
2024-02-12T14:09:28.005984+00:00 ubuntuserver dovecot: master: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=15137 uid=0 code=kill)
2024-02-12T14:09:29.212935+00:00 ubuntuserver dovecot: log(14808): Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)
2024-02-12T14:09:29.238143+00:00 ubuntuserver dovecot: master: Dovecot v2.3.20 (80a5ac675d) starting up without any protocols (core dumps disabled)
2024-02-12T14:09:56.110496+00:00 ubuntuserver dovecot: master: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=15240 uid=0 code=kill)
2024-02-12T14:09:57.219799+00:00 ubuntuserver dovecot: log(15144): Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)
2024-02-12T14:10:19.304639+00:00 ubuntuserver dovecot: master: Dovecot v2.3.20 (80a5ac675d) starting up without any protocols (core dumps disabled)
2024-02-12T14:17:08.208276+00:00 ubuntuserver dovecot: master: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=15403 uid=0 code=kill)
2024-02-12T14:17:51.699300+00:00 ubuntuserver dovecot: master: Fatal: service(auth) getpwnam(vmail) failed: No such file or directory (See service auth { unix_listener /run/dovecot/auth-userdb { user } } setting)
2024-02-12T14:20:12.659665+00:00 ubuntuserver dovecot: master: Dovecot v2.3.20 (80a5ac675d) starting up without any protocols (core dumps disabled)
2024-02-12T14:20:16.125234+00:00 ubuntuserver dovecot: master: Fatal: Dovecot is already running with PID 15458 (read from /run/dovecot/master.pid)
2024-02-12T14:23:02.638927+00:00 ubuntuserver postfix/qmgr[11248]: 28293E2048: from=<>, size=2264, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
2024-02-12T14:23:32.862495+00:00 ubuntuserver postfix/smtp[15599]: connect to test.com[67.225.146.248]:25: Connection timed out
2024-02-12T14:23:32.874891+00:00 ubuntuserver postfix/smtp[15599]: 28293E2048: to=<test@test.com>, relay=none, delay=4766, delays=4735/0.02/30/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to test.com[67.225.146.248]:25: Connection timed out)
2024-02-12T14:28:02.143106+00:00 ubuntuserver postfix/qmgr[11248]: E91F8E1F28: from=<>, size=2244, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
2024-02-12T14:28:32.366768+00:00 ubuntuserver postfix/smtp[15627]: connect to test.com[67.225.146.248]:25: Connection timed out
2024-02-12T14:28:32.390745+00:00 ubuntuserver postfix/smtp[15627]: E91F8E1F28: to=<test@test.com>, relay=none, delay=4575, delays=4545/0.02/30/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to test.com[67
```

This is from nmap -p 192.168.1.16:

```
Starting Nmap 7.94SVN ( https://nmap.org ) at 2024-02-12 14:32 UTC
Nmap scan report for ubunturealm (192.168.1.16)
Host is up (0.000035s latency).

PORT    STATE  SERVICE
143/tcp closed imap

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.05 seconds
```

This is from dovecot -n:

```
# 2.3.20 (80a5ac675d): /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# Pigeonhole version 0.5.20 (149edcf2)
# OS: Linux 6.5.0-17-generic x86_64 Ubuntu 23.10 
# Hostname: ubuntuserver
```

Can someone help me, guide me into correct configuration ?

Answer (score 1):

The errors

- `Fatal: service(imap) access(/usr/lib/dovecot/imap) failed: No such file or directory`

and

- `Fatal: service(pop3) access(/usr/lib/dovecot/pop3) failed: No such file or directory`

suggest you have only installed the `dovecot-core` package, but failed to install support for either the POP3 or IMAP protocol...

You most likely still need to install:

- the `dovecot-imapd` package - the Dovecot secure POP3/IMAP server - IMAP daemon
- the `dovecot-pop3d` package - the Dovecot secure POP3/IMAP server - POP3 daemon

Comment: They are installed, what else it can be?

Comment: @Doujinx Well, you will have to do some digging. Are the files `pop3` and `imap` there? Is their executable bit set? Can you run them manually? If not, does reinstalling the packages help? etc...

Comment: Possibly incorrectly setup `chroot`?